# MSO Word Academic Writing with Figure/Table Referencing

Tags: microsoft-word, title

There has a function in the new MSO Word, that is to insert the title for figures or table. By using this function you will get a field which contains a number, and the number will automatically update depends on its location to the article.

But what I want is not only this.

I need to write in the main text:
"According to the Figure 3... balabala"

Then if I make changes to the order of the figures, for example, figure 3 now becomes figure 5. (the title of the figures will automatically update because of the field generated by the function I mentioned above). I want in my main text Figure 3 will also been modified into Figure 5.

- I cannot directly copy the fields from title to my main text, if I do so it will be counted, i.e. (*in main text:* According to the Figure 3.....; *title of Figure 3:* Figure 4)

If you have any problems with understanding this problem, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to use are the captions created using the right-click context menu's Insert Caption item. You can then use the References>Captions>Cross-Reference dialog to choose Reference Type Figure/Table as applicable, and finally select the way you want the cross reference to appear using the Insert Reference Number To drop-down.

Unfortunately, if you need your references to contain the page number and Table/Figure number you'll need to add two references. One to the item with how you want the reference to look and a second to add the page number.

After better than 30 years, MS still refuses to provide the any sort of real cross-reference building blocks.

Comment: lol thanks, seems better to using latex with big project.

Comment: Almost any DTP tool is better than word, the exceotion being MS publish. I prefer FrameMaker. IMHO, it's the most suited to work with large,  complex documents.  Especially if you mudt use any sort of complex (and dependable) formatting.